# how to give prompt for yii dependent dropdown once the value is passed from database

Tags: yii, dropdown

I have created a dependent dropdown that shows delivery time for selected area,by default it will show aprompt which i have given at the view page but when i choose an area it directly displays the values with first value as selected ,how can i give a prompt instead the first value get selected .here my action

```
public function actionGetdeliveryforarea()
    {
        $data=Areatimeslot::model()->findAll('area_id=:area_id', 
                      array(':area_id'=>(int) $_POST['area_id']));

        $data=CHtml::listData($data,'deliverytime','timeName');
        foreach($data as $value=>$deliverytime)
        {
            echo CHtml::tag('option',
                       array('value'=>$value,),CHtml::encode($deliverytime),true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your action as follows

```
public function actionGetdeliveryforarea()
    {
        $data=Areatimeslot::model()->findAll('area_id=:area_id', 
                      array(':area_id'=>(int) $_POST['area_id']));

        $data=CHtml::listData($data,'deliverytime','timeName');
echo CHtml::tag('option',
                       array('value'=>'',),CHtml::encode("Select Value"),true);
        foreach($data as $value=>$deliverytime)
        {
            echo CHtml::tag('option',
                       array('value'=>$value,),CHtml::encode($deliverytime),true);
        }
    }
```